# using openpyxl copy worksheet from the first sheet， then rename them with name which in a list

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have a name tuple and I have a template worksheet. Now I want to copy the first worksheet, the times of copy are the number of the names (in the tuple), and the copied worksheets are renamed with all the names

```py
wBookTongJi = openpyxl.load_workbook('D:\\example.xlsx')
tupleRequestStaff = ['Ross', 'Joy', 'Monica']

# from this I don't know how to code
for i in listRequestStaff
wBookTongJi.copy_worksheet(wBookTongJi['Sheet1']).title=...
```

Comment: @ Colin, if you can be little more clear, an example would help

Comment: sorry， I am good at English, let alone asking a code question

Comment: @ Colin, keep Stacking, you will get help from this community ... best wishes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just figure out my own problem

```
tupleRequestStaff=('Ross', 'Richul', 'Joy')
for i in range(len(tupleRequestStaff)):
    wBookTongJi.copy_worksheet(wBookTongJi['Sheet1']).title = 
    tupleRequestStaff[i]
    wBookTongJi.save('D:\\Users\\6-7.xlsx')
wBookTongJi.remove(wBookTongJi['Sheet1'])
wBookTongJi.save('D:\\Users\\6-7.xlsx')
```